# unix command to find most recent directory created

Tags: shell, unix, find, unix-timestamp

I want to copy the files from the most recent **directory** created. How would I do so in unix?

For example, if I have the directories names as date stamp as such:

```
/20110311
/20110318
/20110325
```

Comment: Creation time isn't stored in Unix. You'll have to settle for last-modified time.

Comment: last-modified time is what I want for the direcotry. How do I get that? Would I use `find` for that?

Comment: Any time a file is added to a directory, the directory's last-modified time is updated.  Is that okay?

Comment: And, are your directories always named according to a YYYYMMDD date pattern?  Because that would make solutions easier.  :-)   Not sure how you cope if more than one directory is created in a single day, though!

Comment: @Juilus - yes, I am using the YYYYMMDD date as my pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the answer to the question I think you are asking.

When I deal with many directories that have date/time stamps in the name, I always take the approach that you have which is *YYYYMMDD* - the great thing about that is that the date order is then also the alphabetical order. In most shells (certainly in bash and I am 90% sure of the others), the '*' expansion is done alphabetically, and by default '*ls*' return alphabetical order. Hence

```
    ls | head -1
    ls | tail -1
```

Give you the earliest and the latest dates in the directory.

This can be extended to only keep the last 5 entries etc.

Comment: that's basically what i need. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this would work well for me in the case that I do need the top 2-3 latest dirs created. `ls | tail -2`

Answer (score 6):

```
lastdir=`ls -tr &lt;parentdir&gt; | tail -1`
```

I don't know how to make the backticks play nice with the commenting system here. Just replace those apostrophes with backticks.

Comment: In bash you can use $(...) instead of backticks.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting, I came up with the following:

The unix *stat* command is useful here.  The '-t' option causes *stat* to print its output in terse mode (all in one line), and the 13th element of that terse output is the unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) for the last-modified time.  This command will list all directories (and sub-directories) in order from newest-modified to oldest-modified:

```
find -type d -exec stat -t {} \; | sort -r -n -k 13,13
```

Hopefully the "terse" mode of *stat* will remain consistent in future releases of *stat* !

Here's some explanation of the command-line options used:

```
find -type d                # only find directories
find -exec [command] {} \;  # execute given command against each *found* file.
sort -r                     # reverse the sort
sort -n                     # numeric sort (100 should not appear before 2!)
sort -k M,N                 # only sort the line using elements M through N.
```

Returning to your original request, to copy files, maybe try the following.  To output just a single directory (the *most* recent), append this to the command (notice the initial pipe), and feed it all into your 'cp' command with backticks.

```
| head --lines=1 | sed 's/\ .*$//'
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Very interesting. Can you edit this so I can see the entire command? I'm not sure if i'm trying this correctly. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with the ls based solutions is that they are not filtering just for directories. I think this:

```
cp `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec stat -c "%Y %n" {} \;  |sort -n -r |head -1 |awk '{print $2}'`/* /target-directory/.
```

might do the trick, though note that that will only copy files in the immediate directory. If you want a more general answer for copying anything below your newest directory over to a new directory I think you would be better off using rsync like:

```
rsync -av `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec stat -c "%Y %n" {} \;  |sort -n -r |head -1 |awk '{print $2}'`/ /target-directory/
```

but it depends a bit which behaviour you want. The explanation of the stuff in the backticks is:

- `.` - the current directory (you may want to specify an absolute path here)
- `-mindepth/-maxdepth` - restrict the find command only to the immediate children of the current directory
- `-type d` - only directories
- `-exec stat ..` - outputs the modified time and the  name of the directory from find
- `sort -n -r |head -1 | awk '{print $2}'` - date orders the directory and outputs the name of the most recently modified

Answer (score 2):

If your directories are named `YYYYMMDD` like your question suggests, take advantage of the alphabetic globbing.

Put all directories in an array, and then **pick the first one**:

```
dirs=(*/); first_dir="$dirs";
```

(This is actually a shortcut for `first_dir="${dirs[0]}";`.)

Similarly, for **the last one**:

```
dirs=(*/); last_dir="${dirs[$((${#dirs[@]} - 1))]}";
```

Ugly syntax, but this is what it breaks down to:

```
# Create an array of all directories inside the working directory.
dirs=(*/);

# Get the number of entries in the array.
num_dirs=${#dirs[@]};

# Calculate the index of the last entry.
last_index=$(($num_dirs - 1));

# Get the value at the last index.
last_dir="${dirs[$last_index]}";
```

---

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer, but I think this method is preferable as it does everything in Bash. No reason to spawn extra processes, let alone [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). (Which, admittedly, should be fine in this particular case of `YYYYMMDD` names.)

Comment: supertrue: not in Bash, or at least not that I am aware of. Were you trying it in the plain old Bourne shell `sh`?

Comment: No, I use Bash (Mac Terminal), I was just wondering what the meaning of it was, given that # is also used for comments.

Comment: Ah, I see. It has special meaning when it's inside a variables with braces. `${#foo}` counts the number of characters in a normal (string) variable called `foo`, and `${foo[@]}` counts the number of elements in an array called `foo`. See [Bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

please try with following command
      ls -1tr | tail -1

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~ -type d | ls -ltra
```

This one is simple and useful which I learned recently.
This command will show the results in reverse chronological order.

Comment: ls does not take pipes

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a command that can be used to identify which folder or files are created in a folder as a newest. That's seems pure :)

```
#/bin/sh
path=/var/folder_name

newest=`find $path -maxdepth 1 -exec stat -t {} \; |sed 1d |sort -r -k 14 | head -1 |awk {'print $1'} | sed 's/\.\///g'`

find $path -maxdepth 1| sed 1d |grep -v $newest
```